# Android cocos2d animation

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I have make 1 animation in cocos2d game, but not able to see that animation. Can anyone please help?

```
Animation animation = new Animation("dance", 0.2f);
        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            animation.addFrame(new CCFormatter().format("grossini_dance_%02d.png", i));
        }

        IntervalAction action = Animate.action(animation);

        grossini.runAction(action);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public void addPuzzleAnimation() {

            CCAnimation OpenPuzzleAnim = CCAnimation.animation("", 0.1f);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
                if (i < 10) {
                    OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("trunkOut.0" + i + ".png"));
                } else {
                    OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("trunkOut." + i + ".png"));
                }
                CCAction OpenPuzzleAction = CCAnimate.action(1, OpenPuzzleAnim, false);
                addboxPuzzleOpen.runAction(OpenPuzzleAction);

            }
```